# Mac Cursor Folder

Tags: macos

I've been researching for a couple hours now, and I want to find my Mac system default cursor.  Not any mouseover, I just want the default cursor.  I am running one of the older versions of Mac, which is:  10.4.11;

I was told that the cursors are in here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HiServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors
```

But, there seems to be no Cursors folder in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HiServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/
```

Please help.  I want a smoothy. :P

Comment: What are you trying to find it for? If you are writing a Cocoa app you can do `(NSCursor*) defaultCursor = [NSCursor arrowCursor];`

Comment: I just want the cursors!  I want to copy the cursors and upload them and use them on my Windows system. ;P

Comment: Try opening a terminal window and doing `sudo find / -name "arrow"` or `sudo find / -name "cursors"`. That may take some time to run. You might be able to narrow it down by looking in /System instead of /. Using that I was able to find my cursor directory but the one cursor it didn't have was the default arrow. It was here `/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors`

Comment: @user1087981 The one cursor I am looking for is the default arrow. :p

Comment: Does anyone know where the spinning beach ball of death cursor is stored?

Answer (score 7):

The default arrow needs to be displayed at times when the rest of the system may not be available (e.g. at boot) so it is probably stored in a special place such as in the hardware itself.

The closest image to the default cursor is probably the "contextual menu", here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors/contextualmenu/cursor_1only_.png
```

With some minor edits you could probably turn this image into a whole arrow picture.

Most other cursors have images in WebKit, here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Resources/
```

Comment: It doesn't have default arrow.

Comment: I added some info on how you might produce an arrow.

Comment: I don't have the cursors folder.

Comment: I searched on a system running 10.7; I have a 10.3 setup too, I will try to look on it later to see where they put things back then.

Answer (score 7):

After doing a bit of digging, I found this:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EFILogin.framework/Versions/A/Resources/EFIResourceBuilder.bundle/Contents/Resources/loginui_cursor@2x.png
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: That's not the right cursor, it doesn't have a sharp lower left point.

Comment: This is amazing! Serious question though: how do you guys find these kind of folders? Is there a special OSX manual about it, or a special search program, or do you just happen to know approximately where to look? Thx!

Comment: These files don't have an `info.plist` like the ones stored in the `cursors` directory. Do those exist somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the image programatically:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

let cursor = NSCursor.arrowCursor().image.TIFFRepresentation

let searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

let documentsPath = searchPaths[0] as! String
let savePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("cursor.tiff")

cursor?.writeToFile(savePath, atomically: true)
```

The result is a tiff with 4 different versions of the cursor, ranging from 20x24 pixels (non-retina default) to 200x240 pixels. Using Preview.app, you can grab each individual size and copy/paste into a new document, saving each as a png.

Or just grab one I prepared earlier: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/147461/mac-cursor/mac-cursor.zip