# How to adjust or deviate from the default JavaFX transfer mode behavior

Tags: java, javafx

I have successfully implemented Drag and Drop in JavaFX. Both the drag source and destination are happy to support both copy and move transfer modes, so I use `TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE` on both ends.

In this case, I believe JavaFX **correctly** defaults to using the copy transfer mode as the default. I base this correctness on a [UX question and answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/what-are-the-most-common-modifier-keys-for-dragging-objects-with-a-mouse), although it seems clear there may not be an absolute standard. JavaFX will switch to the move transfer mode if the SHIFT key is pressed.

Nonetheless, I would prefer *move* be the default and copy only be engaged via a key modifier. I have searched the web, and in the code, but I can find no way to adjust this default behavior. Does anyone know a way? I also tried using the individual transfer mode enums in case order matters, but that didn't work either.

I have further considered attempting to capture a key event, and then simply either accept move or copy at the destination based on what modifier might be down. However, my concern is whether the destination will have the focus and whether the key event will propagate during a drag. I will try this approach, but decided to also ask if anyone here knew of an alternative (or even if perhaps the ability to change the default would come in Java 9).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to support drag&drop to external applications or only inside your own?

Comment: Only inside my application.

Comment: It's pretty easy to test if the shift key is down when the drag is initiated (from within the application): the handler for `onDragDetected` takes a `MouseEvent`, which has an `isShiftDown()` method. That wouldn't allow the user to modify the behavior during the drag; I don't know how important that is to you. The easiest way to have a "global" test for the shift key is probably to use event filters on the (one for key pressed, one for key released) on the `Scene`.

Comment: @James_D Thanks, I had not considered checking at the start. The exact behavior isn't critical (probably), but it would be nice to be able to adjust modes during the drag. This happens today (only, the behavior is the inverse of what I'd like). I'll be dragging (potentially) between two scenes (even two instances of the app). I wasn't sure if source or destination would be responding to key events (I assume I need the destination to). I admitted I haven't yet explored this avenue. It sounds like that will be the next step.

Comment: To follow-up, I tried a key event filter, but the destination (the drop target) didn't get the events (the source did). This makes sense (to me), as it has the focus. I did consider that since I am receiving the events (at the source), and I control both sides, I could come up with a novel way to get that information to the destination. In the end, that seems like a road to far to travel for my needs. I did notice that default JavaFX does adjust to key presses, even across application instances, even on the instance in the background. So, it's possible, but perhaps not public / configurable.

Comment: Follow up years later w/ OpenJFX12: When you select TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE in onDragDetected, you can then add an onDragOver handler which will receive events with updated transfer modes in response to pressing Shift or Ctrl etc. during the drag.  But the default still seems to be COPY, and details depend on the OS. On Linux, holding Shift changes to MOVE.

Answer (score 0):

I had a need for this very thing.  Plenty of native applications already behave this way:  dragging is a move operation by default, and holding down a certain modifier key, whether before the drag or during the drag, changes the drag to a copy operation.  As of JavaFX 19, there still is no way to programmatically modify the transfer mode of a native platform drag-and-drop once it’s in progress. (By “native platform drag-and-drop” I mean a drag-and-drop started with [Node.startDragAndDrop](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#startDragAndDrop(javafx.scene.input.TransferMode...)).)

However, you mentioned in a comment that your drag-and-drop is only within your application.  This means you can forego the native platform functionality, and do it yourself with only a little more work, using a non-native JavaFX drag-and-drop which is started by [Node.startFullDrag](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#startFullDrag()).

(Why the JavaFX calls a native platform drag-and-drop just “drag and drop” and calls a non-native, JavaFX-implemented drag-and-drop “full drag and drop” is beyond me.  I had to read the javadocs several times before I was able to keep the nomenclature straight in my head.)

While native platform drag-and-drop uses [DragEvents](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/DragEvent.html), the JavaFX-implemented drag-and-drop uses [MouseDragEvents](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseDragEvent.html).  (This is apparently in keeping with the tradition of obfuscative terminology when it comes to drag-and-drop in JavaFX.)

The big challenge is finding the underlying system’s drag-and-drop cursors:

- [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553826/mac-cursor-folder#comment15280429_11553826) rightly points out the location of system cursors, including drag-and-drop cursors, on Macs.  Whether that information will hold true in the long term, I have no idea.  The good news is, the cursors appear to be ordinary .png files.  The bad news is, their hotspots are defined in [binary plist](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFBinaryPList.c.auto.html) files in the same directory as each .png file.
- JavaFX for Linux uses Gnome/GTK, so it makes sense to use Gnome cursors.  They are in the `cursors` subdirectory of the active theme, as [Xcursor](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xcursor) image files;  for my code below, I used [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) to convert them to PNG files.  (I couldn’t find any other tools capable of reading Xcursor files.)  Finding the current Gnome theme is a bit complex;  the full [icon theme spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) depends on the [XDG base directory spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) and a command like `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme` to find the current theme’s name.  Parsing Xcursor images in Java is not impossible, but I found it needed a nontrivial amount of code.
- Windows drag-and-drop cursors [are buried in ole32.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487213/1831987).  A .dll file follows the [Portable Executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) format.  I found it fairly difficult to read the file using Java, as the relative offsets’ bases aren’t well explained (and the rest of the Internet seems even more confused than I was), but I did get there eventually.  Oh, and each cursor’s image data is a BMP/DIB which is missing the 14-byte header;  fortunately that is easy to synthesize.

Anyway, here is an example using JavaFX-implemented drag-and-drop, without all of the work involved in finding the system’s cursors:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.ImageCursor;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class DragAndDropMoveByDefault
extends Application {
    private Label sourceLabel;
    private Label destLabel;

    private boolean dragging;

    private boolean copyModifierPressed;

    private boolean overPossibleDropTarget;

    private Cursor copyCursor;
    private Cursor moveCursor;
    private Cursor cannotDropCursor;

    private KeyCode copyModifierKey;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        boolean mac = System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac");
        copyModifierKey = (mac ? KeyCode.ALT : KeyCode.CONTROL);
        Predicate<MouseEvent> isCopyModifierDown =
            e -> (mac ? e.isAltDown() : e.isControlDown());

        copyCursor = new ImageCursor(new Image(
            getClass().getResource("dnd-copy.png").toString()));
        moveCursor = new ImageCursor(new Image(
            getClass().getResource("dnd-move.png").toString()));
        cannotDropCursor = new ImageCursor(new Image(
            getClass().getResource("dnd-none.png").toString()));

        sourceLabel = new Label(LocalTime.now().toString());
        destLabel = new Label(" ");

        sourceLabel.setStyle("-fx-padding: 100; -fx-border-style: solid;");
        destLabel.setStyle("-fx-padding: 100; -fx-border-style: solid;");

        sourceLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        destLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        sourceLabel.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            dragging = true;
            overPossibleDropTarget = false;
            copyModifierPressed = isCopyModifierDown.test(e);
            sourceLabel.startFullDrag();
            updateCursor();
            e.consume();
        });
        destLabel.setOnMouseDragExited(e -> {
            overPossibleDropTarget = false;
            updateCursor();
            e.consume();
        });
        destLabel.setOnMouseDragEntered(e -> {
            copyModifierPressed = isCopyModifierDown.test(e);
            overPossibleDropTarget = true;
            updateCursor();
            e.consume();
        });
        destLabel.setOnMouseDragOver(e -> {
            copyModifierPressed = isCopyModifierDown.test(e);
            overPossibleDropTarget = true;
            updateCursor();
            e.consume();
        });
        destLabel.setOnMouseDragReleased(e -> {
            destLabel.setText(sourceLabel.getText());
            if (!copyModifierPressed) {
                sourceLabel.setText("");
            }
            dragging = false;
            updateCursor();
            e.consume();
        });

        TilePane pane = new TilePane(12, 0, sourceLabel, destLabel);
        pane.setPrefColumns(2);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(6));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (dragging && e.getCode() == copyModifierKey) {
                copyModifierPressed = true;
                updateCursor();
            }
        });
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (dragging && e.getCode() == copyModifierKey) {
                copyModifierPressed = false;
                updateCursor();
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Drag and Drop - Move by Default");
        stage.show();
    }

    private void updateCursor() {
        Cursor cursor;
        if (dragging) {
            if (overPossibleDropTarget) {
                cursor = (copyModifierPressed ? copyCursor : moveCursor);
            } else {
                cursor = cannotDropCursor;
            }
        } else {
            cursor = Cursor.DEFAULT;
        }

        sourceLabel.setCursor(cursor);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```