# Using the Windows Drag Copy cursor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouse-cursor

I can set a cursor like this:

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
```

Using IntelliSense, I don't find this "Copy" cursor:

[image: Copy Cursor]

Is there any way to get it in a managed way?
I wouldn't want to load a bitmap or so.
I would like to leave that up to Windows as the user may have changed the cursor size or set a different color schema.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Drag and drop cursors belong `ole32.dll`. You can load them from that library. To do so, you need to load `ole32.dll` using [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), then using [`LoadCursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) get the handle of those cursors. You can use 1 to 7 as `LoadCursor` parameter to get cursors from `ole32.dll`. The cursor which you are looking for is `3` or `6`:

[image]

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, UInt16 lpCursorName);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var l = LoadLibrary("ole32.dll");
    var h = LoadCursor(l, 6);
    this.Cursor = new Cursor(h);
}
```

Comment: The image which I shared in this post has taken from exported cursors. I exported those cursors using Visual studio File→Open. You always can do the same for cursors, icons and other resources. You also can rely on adding them as embedded resource to your application. Also if it's a standard drag and drop operation, it's better to rely on standard cursors which is set based on `e.Effect` in drag&drop events.

Comment: System.Windows.Input.Cursor doesn't have a constructor that accepts IntPtr. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: @NigelBess It's a Windows Forms answer, look at [Cursor Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-5.0).

Comment: @NigelBess I posted a WPF question and answer to show [How to create a WPF Cursor from an IntPtr handle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69384509/3110834).

Comment: funny we both found the same solution and created the same question and answer: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381624/how-do-you-use-a-cursor-from-ole32-dll-in-a-wpf-application/69381832#69381832) is my question and answer from earlier today.

Comment:  Cool! Glad to hear that you solved it. @NigelBess