# How to create a WPF Cursor from an IntPtr handle

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, .net-core

Assuming I have handle of a cursor and I'd like to create an instance of WPF Cursor using that handle.

In Windows Forms, [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-5.0) class has a constructor which accepts IntPtr, but WPF [System.Windows.Input.Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.cursor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-5.0) doesn't have a constructor that accepts IntPtr. Any idea how to get around this and create a WPF Cursor from IntPtr handle?

For example, the following piece of code (borrowed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487213/3110834))works in Windows Forms, but I'd like to write the equivalent in WPF:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, UInt16 lpCursorName);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var l = LoadLibrary("ole32.dll");
    var h = LoadCursor(l, 6);
    this.Cursor = new Cursor(h);
}
```

Comment: This post inspired by a question asked in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485890/using-the-windows-drag-copy-cursor/49487213#comment122631764_49487213).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [CursorInteropHelper.Create(SafeHandle)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.cursorinterophelper.create?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-5.0) which accepts a [SafeHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-5.0), then you can use it like this:

```
CursorInteropHelper.Create(theSafeHandle);
```

So you need to create an instance of `SafeHandle` using an `IntPtr`. But, now the problem is the SafeHandle class is abstract! Since there's no implementation available in [Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-5.0) for cursor handle, you can create one by deriving from [SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandlezeroorminusoneisinvalid?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-5.0) class:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public sealed class SafeCursorHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool DestroyCursor(IntPtr handle);

    public SafeCursorHandle() : base(true) { }
    public SafeCursorHandle(IntPtr handle) : base(true)
    {
        SetHandle(handle);
    }
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return DestroyCursor(handle);
    }
}
```

Finally, to put everything in a WPF example which does the same thing as the Windows Forms example:

```
//using System;
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//using System.Windows;
//using System.Windows.Interop;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, UInt16 lpCursorName);

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var l = LoadLibrary("ole32.dll");
    var h = LoadCursor(l, 6);
    this.Cursor = CursorInteropHelper.Create(new SafeCursorHandle(h));
}
```